# Ionic conditionally add service provider

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dependency-injection, ionic3

What I wanna achieve is add `providers` conditionally, as follow:

made an `interface`:

```
export interface StorageInterface {
    Storage(): any;
    SwitchStorage(isLocal: boolean): void;
    ClearStorage(): void;
    Setter(key: string, value: any): void;
    Getter(key: string): any;
}
```

then made a `class` to `implement` it:

```
export class IonicStorage implements StorageInterface {


    get User(): User {
        return {};
    }
    set User(value: User) {

    }
    constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => Storage)) private storage: Storage) {

    }

    Storage() {
        return this.storage;
    }

    SwitchStorage(isLocal: boolean): void {

    }
    ClearStorage(): void {
        this.storage.clear();
    }

    Setter(key: string, value: any): void {

    }
    Getter(key: string) {

    }
}
```

then a `module` to handle providers etc..

```
@NgModule({})
export class APIModule {
  static forRoot(config?: Configuration) {
    // if (config)
    //   will use it latter to inject diff providers 

    let mod = {
      ngModule: APIModule,
      imports: [

      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: 'StorageInterface', useClass: IonicStorage },
        StorageService,
        AuthService,
      ]
    };


    return mod;
  }
}
```

and I made `StorageService` to play as the `middle man` / `proxy` :

```
@Injectable()
export class StorageService implements StorageInterface {
    constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => 'StorageInterface')) private storage: StorageInterface) {

    }

    Storage() {
        return this.storage;
    }

    SwitchStorage(isLocal: boolean): void {
        this.storage.SwitchStorage(isLocal);
    }

    ClearStorage(): void {
        this.storage.ClearStorage();
    }

    Setter(key: string, value: any): void {
        this.storage.Setter(key, value);
    }

    Getter(key: string) {
        return this.storage.Getter(key);
    }


}
```

so I can inject `StorageService` to any `page/component` etc , and it automatically uses the class I set in the module `usesClass` .

eg:

```
export class HomePage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http, private storage: StorageService) {
//storage should be IonicStorage
} 
}
```

but it errors out :

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Storage! Error: No provider for Storage! at injectionError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1590:86) at noProviderError
```

where I have added `IonicStorageModule` to the main `NgModule` , what is missing here?

Comment: Side note: `Consider using a class instead of an interface` - Angular style guide: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces

Comment: @Sampath I have tried with `class` and with `abstract` , same issue , not really sure , what is wrong with `Storage` provider , it's supposed to be referenced!

Comment: No, I have given a **best coding practice guideline**. Not a solution for your issue.

Comment: Just a few notes here: I think your `StorageInterface` should be an abstract class with abstract methods. This class is then extended by e.g. `IonicStorage`. In your module in the providers array you can use the config dynamically as follows (where `config` has to be an object in form `{ provide: <Class>, useClass: <Class> }`: `config || { provide: StorageInterface, useClass: IonicStorage}`. Notice that you actually have to provide a `StorageInterface` instance not just a string. I don't really see why you need your `StorageService`, you could just make `IonicStorage` an `@Injectable`.

Comment: @David I tried that, before trying the interface , both produce the same error!

Comment: @Abanoub Well, thats only one point. Did you also read through the rest?

Comment: @David you can't really provide an `interface` as `provide`, I had to make it string , and then , inject it by doing this `@Inject(forwardRef(() => 'StorageInterface')) private storage: StorageInterface`

Comment: @Abanoub Yeah thats one of the reasons why I would not recommend using an `interface` in your case. Have a look at the source of [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core), I think the repo pretty much implements what you are trying to do - looking at the conecept of course, not the use-case.